# Newsletter background image repeats in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, background-image, outlook-2010, newsletter

I have big prolems with email html newsletter with Outlook desktop client.
My background repeats horizontaly just in outlook.With other web clients and mobile it looks perfect. I already checked some topics here but I didnt found right solution.

Here is my code .Can you tell me guys where Im wrong:

http://pastebin.com/aQQMPPHQ

```
    <table style="padding: 0px 15px; font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table style="padding: 0px; font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center"><tbody><tr><td style="background-image: url('http://www.miro-reisen.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/miro-reisen-newsletter-extended.jpg'); background-position: center top; background-repeat: no-repeat;" align="center"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
             <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
               <v:fill type="tile" src="http://www.miro-reisen.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/miro-reisen-newsletter-extended.jpg" color="#00bbe3"/>
             </v:background>
             <![endif]--> <!-- head table -->
<table style="font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
```

That newsletter-extened.jpg repeats on the right side horizontaly

Comment: Have you have background-repeat: repeat; ? I cannot access your pastebin could you paste the code into your question?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me too, just wanted to post an answer as I finally fixed the problem in my e-mail. I added **style="background-repeat: no-repeat;** inline to every single image in the html and it fixed it.